# Remove grid view from catalogsearch

Tags: product-list, catalogsearch, toolbar

I know how to manage the grid/list view in the back end, and set pager limits via the XML but is it possible to remove the grid view from just the catalogsearch result page preferably via the XML?

I've had a search and can't seem to find a way to do this anywhere.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catalog (category) and catalogsearch (results) contexts use the same block classes and templates. Unfortunately there are no public methods for setting/adjusting the `_availableModes` property after it's been set - which it is in the constructor for `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`. (There is a `setModes()` method but it does nothing once the property is populated).

It would be possible to set a custom template using the `catalogsearch_result_index` and `catalogsearch_advanced_result` handles, and then in your template, check for the `grid` array key and `unset()` it. Not as clean as being part of the block, but the block wasn't made very friendly anyway.